# Select where last activity 3 months ago

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table of cellular invoices, relevant columns are `Cellular_Account_id (INT)`, `billing_end_date(DATE)`, and `data_usage_GB`.

There is a separate row for each account every month. I'm trying to get a list of accounts that have had no data usage for each of the past three months.

I'm pretty new to databases in general, so I'm not really even sure what syntax I should be searching for, or what approach I should be taking.

I can, of course, select `WHERE data_usage_GB = 0.000 AND MONTH(billing_end_date) = month(current_date()) -1` but that only gives me the info in 1 month's range. I'm not sure how to group together the results where `data_usage_GB = 0.000` for each of the last three months.

Comment: You want to select accounts (from the asccounts table obviously) where *not exists* any invoice within the last three months. SQL has a `NOT EXISTS` clause. Look it up. You should also have a look at MySQL date/time functions in their docs.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: @Eric - So far I've tried simple select statements on a particular month - which is fine, but it doesn't get the aggregate data that I'm looking for. Still, I should have mentioned that up front. Thanks for the reminder, original question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd group by the account, get the maximum date for each and then filter them using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   cellular_account_id
FROM     invoices
GROUP BY cellular_account_id
HAVING   MAX(billing_end_date) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` is the bit I was missing, thanks! I'm having to learn MySQL a little at a time for my job, so there are plenty of gaps like that. Now I have something to search for to learn more about what I can do with it.

I ended up using the following:
`SELECT * FROM cellular_invoices
WHERE data_usage_GB = 0.000
GROUP BY cellular_account_id
HAVING MAX(billing_end_date) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`